# What is the "match" referring to in this argument in this code example

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, arguments

I am trying to learn how to parse JSON data using Google Sheets and I am using this website as an example. However, while I've managed to figure out most of the code, there is one part of the code I don't understand what it is doing. 'match' is used in the function as a parameter, but I don't see it referred anywhere else. In the attached code, what is 'match' referring to?

```
/**
 * Parse JSON and render the results in a string template.
 *
 * @param {"url"} url
 *        JSON API data URL
 * @param {"templateText"} template
 *        string template for rendering results
 * @customfunction
 */
function JSONTEMPLATE(url, template) {
    url = encodeURI(url);
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var obj = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    var result = template.replace(/\{\{\s*(.*?)\s*\}\}/g, function(match, varName) {
        return obj[varName];
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, the website where I got this code from is from here: https://thisdavej.com/consuming-json-web-data-using-google-sheets/

Comment: It's the matched substring from the regular expression. You can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Comment: The referred functions isn't a [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), it's just a function used as argument of a method.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). In short, when passing in a function as the second parameter to `replace()`;

> You can specify a function as the second parameter. In this case, the
>   function will be invoked after the match has been performed. The
>   function's result (return value) will be used as the replacement
>   string. (Note: the above-mentioned special replacement patterns do not
>   apply in this case.) Note that the function will be invoked multiple
>   times for each full match to be replaced if the regular expression in
>   the first parameter is global.
>
> **match**:    The matched substring. (Corresponds to $& above.)

In your case, this would be any special characters.